# Descargar archivo con PHP

Tags: php, django, codeigniter

quiero descargar un archivo que me provee un servidor con Django, lo intento con curl pero me crea un pdf vacio. Lo estoy intentando con:

```
$headers = array(
  'Content-Type:application/json',
  'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode( usuario:contrasena )
);
$host = "url";
$ch = curl_init( $host );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30 );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
$return = curl_exec( $ch );
$error = curl_error($ch);
curl_close( $ch );
$destination = "./test2.pdf";
$file = fopen($destination, "w+");
fputs($file, $return );
fclose($file);
```

Comment: no te da error el servicio?

Comment: No, nada, ni al imprimir $return;

Comment: entonces tu problema es otra cosa intenta probar el servicio con POSTMAn

Comment: Con postman si envio la ruta con el basicAuth me devuelve un formulario para iniciar sesión.

Comment: entonces verifica la authenticacion probablemente ese es el error

Comment: Cuando ingreso la url en el navegador me pide que inicie sesión, lo hago y despues con la sesión iniciada ya me muestra el archivo. ¿Cómo deberia enviar los datos de sesión? ya probé y los que tengo son correctos, quizá es la manera en la que envío los datos de sesión.

Comment: habla con el que te provee el servicio probablemente debes consumir un rest de login y luego agregarlos al header para poder descargarlo

Answer (score 0):

Prueba agregando las siguientes líneas de código:

```
header("Content-type: application/pdf charset= UTF-8" ) ; 
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename= **nombredetuarchivo.pdf**" ) ;

ini_set('display_errors',true); //Activa los errores para verificar que el resto de tu código no esté ocasionando conflicto.
```

Comment: $headers = array(
      'Content-type: application/pdf; charset= UTF-8',
      'Content-Disposition: attachment; filename = Nombre3.pdf',
      'Authorization: Basic '. base64_encode( usuario:contrasena )
    );
Sigue sin funcionar. Muchas gracias por su ayuda